# Text alignment issue with OCR

Tags: android, android-studio, textblock

I created an application for scanning text from an image and write it on a textview ,it worked successfully for single  column of data,But in case of multiple columns it  read columns randomly and not printing the same way as a  table view that the original image appears. I used google vision api and parse the text into a SparseArray of type `textblock(SparseArray<Textblock>)`.

Output screenshot of the scanned image:
[image: Output screenshot of the scanned image]

```
 Frame frame=new Frame.Builder().setBitmap(bitmap).build();
                SparseArray<TextBlock> textBlocks = recognizer.detect(frame);
                String blocks = "";
                String lines = "";
                String words = "";
                for (int index = 0; index < textBlocks.size(); index++) {
                    //extract scanned text blocks here
                    TextBlock tBlock = textBlocks.valueAt(index);
                    blocks = blocks + tBlock.getValue() + "\n" + "\n";
                    for (Text line : tBlock.getComponents()) {
                        //extract scanned text lines here
                        lines = lines + line.getValue() + "\n";
                        for (Text element : line.getComponents()) {
                            //extract scanned text words here
                            words = words + element.getValue() + ", ";
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (textBlocks.size() == 0) {
                    etresult.setText("Scan Failed: Found nothing to scan");
                } else {
                    etresult.setText(etresult.getText() + "Blocks: " + "\n");
                    etresult.setText(etresult.getText() + blocks + "\n");

                    saveToInternalStorage(bitmap);
                }
```

Comment: The api is supposed to scan the text and not the table or the text format!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through above code I can see that the OCR is supposed to scan the image and detect the text not the text alignment like tables and its columns. But you can 
recognise the alignment by using Bounding boxes which gives top-left,top-right,bottom-left,bottom-right corordinates. Please go through Google cloud vision api documentation. https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr